# Unknown default host [localhost] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1 - TomEE start up

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

We have been requested to migrate from Tomcat 1.6 to TomEE. In our application we are using tomcat as an embedded server. When we tried to start TomEE using "org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat" based on the below tutorial "http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/" but we are getting the warning "Unknown default host [localhost] for connector" .

our Server.xml is below.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"
  SSLEngine="on" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
 <GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
   type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
   factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
   pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
 </GlobalNamingResources>
 <Service name="Catalina">
  <Connector port="33557" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
   connectionTimeout="500" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
   maxThreads="10" emptySessionPath="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
   enableLookups="false" />
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
     resourceName="UserDatabase" />
   </Realm>
   <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true"
    autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
     directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
     pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   </Host>
  </Engine>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: I have not used embedded tomcat so only guessing how to start dealing with it bu.... Are you sure this the server.xml which is loaded on startup once you embed your tomcat? What about wht appBase="webapp" where would the folder "webapp" be located if it is embeded.

Comment: The same issue also comes when to deploy a tomee app with connector usage:

      <Host name="tomee.website.com" appBase="/home/test/tomee/webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="tomee.website.com-access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved when I used Tomcat class instead of Catalina to start TomEE server.